# Move Images from Sub folders to Main Folders

Tags: batch-file

I have n number of Sub-folders with images. I want to move all the images to Main Folder for organize them correctly.

**For Example -**

```
C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NeoDownloader\Book Cover\fc02.deviantart.net\fs17\i\2007\225\9\0\front_cover_of_myths_book_by_cathydelanssay.jpg

C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NeoDownloader\Book Cover\fc02.deviantart.net\fs30\i\2008\092\8\7\The_Seagull_by_rei_i.jpg
```

Like the above location, I have more then 2000 image. I want to move all those images in one main Folder.

If the folders names are constant I can Write Batch File. But Those sub-folders are not the same. So I can't specify in the batch file. Its difficult to move without Coding. So help me to organize the Images in My Computer.

**Notes -**

1. All images are jpg format only
2. List item last folder contain only few of
   images, other subfolders not have image file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "inputFolder=C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NeoDownloader"
    set "outputFolder=c:\somewhere"

    for /r "%inputFolder%" %%a in (*.jpg) do (
        if not exist "%outputFolder%\%%~nxa" ( 
            move "%%~fa" "%outputFolder%"
        ) else (
            for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b "%outputFolder%\%%~na_~[*]%%~xa" 2^>nul ^| find /c /v ""') do (
                move "%%~fa" "%outputFolder%\%%~na_~[%%b]%%~xa"
            )
        )
    )
```

Do a recursive enumeration of the files. For each file found, if it does not exist in target folder, move to target. If there is a file with the same name, it is moved with an incremental file name. Not bulletproof but should do the work.

Comment: Thank you MC ND. Is Possible to delete the empty folder from the inputfolderpath?. Because after moving the images my system have more then 5000 empty folders.

Comment: @Sagotharan, as all of the NeoDownloader has been removed, remove it `rd "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NeoDownloader" /s /q` be careful, recursive removal of folders without confirmation.

Comment: Once Again Thank you MC ND. This Batch File gives little interesting. You saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the output directory before running the batch. I learned this the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

I have this python script which should do the job:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

# Pause for a few seconds to give you time to switch to the window you want to automate
time.sleep(10)
print("10sec")

while True:
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("Pressed Enter key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+A keys")
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'x')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+X keys")
    pyautogui.press('backspace')
    print("Pressed Backspace key")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+V keys")
    pyautogui.press('delete')
    print("Pressed Delete key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("Pressed Enter key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('right')
    print("Pressed Right Arrow key")
    pyautogui.press('left')
    print("Pressed Left Arrow key")

    # Listen for the Esc key press and stop the script if detected
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        break
```